# R split values in column

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
 d              f         
 "first tweet"  A
 "second tweet" B
 "thrid tweet"  C
```

And I would like to get this

```
 d              A      B       C         
 "first tweet"  1      0       0
 "second tweet" 0      1       0
 "thrid tweet"  0      0       1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any real reason you need this? R tends to prefer factors to dummy-variable style coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few options to consider:

1. `model.matrix`

   ```
   cbind(mydf, model.matrix(~ 0 + f, data = mydf))
   #              d f fA fB fC
   # 1  first tweet A  1  0  0
   # 2 second tweet B  0  1  0
   # 3  thrid tweet C  0  0  1
   ```
2. `table`

   ```
   cbind(mydf, as.data.frame.matrix(table(sequence(nrow(mydf)), mydf$f)))
   #              d f A B C
   # 1  first tweet A 1 0 0
   # 2 second tweet B 0 1 0
   # 3  thrid tweet C 0 0 1
   ```
3. `dcast` from "reshape2"

   ```
   library(reshape2)
   dcast(mydf, d ~ f, value.var="f", fun.aggregate=length)
   #              d A B C
   # 1  first tweet 1 0 0
   # 2 second tweet 0 1 0
   # 3  thrid tweet 0 0 1
   ```

Note that there is a difference between the first two options and the third one. The third option will collapse (and tabulate) values if there happen to be repeated values for column "d", while the first two split the values out on a row-by-row basis.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
library(qdap)
mtabulate(split(dat[[2]], dat[[1]]))

##              A B C
## first tweet  1 0 0
## second tweet 0 1 0
## thrid tweet  0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple table seems like it might do the trick.

```
> d <- data.frame(d = c("first tweet", "second tweet", "third tweet"),
                  f = c("A", "B", "C"))
> tab <- table(d)
> data.frame(d = rownames(tab), tab[,1:3], row.names = NULL)
#              d A B C
# 1  first tweet 1 0 0
# 2 second tweet 0 1 0
# 3  third tweet 0 0 1
```

Comment: Hi @Richard, indeed is it possible to make the table to be a data.frame?

Comment: @useR, that's there in my answer: `as.data.frame.matrix`.

Comment: @useR, I added the conversion.  Sorry for the delayed response.